# How do I replace the default SIGINT handler when using sigaction?

Tags: unix, signals, rust

I've been playing with `sigaction` in the `nix-rust` crate to try and handle a SIGINT signal in my program and instead do nothing. While I've been able to handle the signal using:

```
let sig_action = signal::SigAction::new(
    handle_signal,
    signal::SockFlag::empty(),
    signal::SigSet::empty()
);
unsafe { signal::sigaction(signal::SIGINT, &sig_action); }
```

It seems no matter what I do in the `handle_signal` function, when it concludes, the SIGINT is still processed and the program exits. My handler does not replace the default functionality, rather it happens before it. What would the function have to do to instead prevent the interrupt from still causing the program to exit?

Comment: This [works for me](http://is.gd/AivmD3) on OS X; I am unable to kill the program with control-C and it prints out "handling" instead. Do note that `signal::sigaction` returns a `Result` that you are ignoring, perhaps you want to add an `unwrap` call to check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `cargo run` to run your program?  If so, it sounds like your program is handling the SIGINT signal and instead cargo is being killed.  Since cargo doesn't have any special handling it is being killed by the signal, thus ending your program.